# transitionFromView does the right thing, BUT without animation. Why?

Tags: iphone, uiview, transition

Here's the code:

```
[UIView transitionFromView:mapView toView:tableView duration:5.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionShowHideTransitionViews|UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft completion:NULL];
```

After calling this method the mapView is hidden and the tableView is visible, but there is no animation! I changed the duration to 5 seconds to make sure that I wouldn't miss the animation, but it really isn't animating. Is there anything wrong with the above line or do I need to do something to activate the animation?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks like you're using the wrong animation option. You need to be using.

```
UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft
```

Currently you're using

```
UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft
```